# Native app install banner not working

Tags: android, json, google-chrome

I cant get a native app install banner to display on android. I've added the following `masifest.json`:

```
{
    "name": "My native app",
    "description": "balh blah blah",
    "short_name": "myapp",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src:": "/Assets/app-install-banner-logo.png",
            "type:": "image/png",
            "sizes:": "144x144"
        }
    ],
    "prefer_related_applications": true,
    "related_applications": [
        {
            "platform": "play",
            "id": "com.my.app"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I look at the application tab in chrome dev tools is see:

[image]

Why isn't are the fields begin populated? The json is valid, I can click on the `/Assets/manifest.json` link and see the contents. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working, two things needed to be done:

1. Open up manifest in sublime and change encoding from `UTF8 with BOM` to `UTF8`
2. Unable to test in chrome or android emulator(as it cannot access the play store). You need to add a proxy to your dev machine on an actual android device and access the running site over https (in my case it involved creating a https iis binding to route through)

Answer (score 1):

Use below example in **manifest.json**

```
{
      "short_name": "Name Of Website",
      "name": "The Website",
      "icons": [
        {
          "src": "launcher-icon-0-75x.png",
          "sizes": "36x36",
          "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
          "src": "launcher-icon-1x.png",
          "sizes": "48x48",
          "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
          "src": "launcher-icon-1-5x.png",
          "sizes": "72x72",
          "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
          "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
          "sizes": "96x96",
          "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
          "src": "launcher-icon-3x.png",
          "sizes": "144x144",
          "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
          "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
          "sizes": "192x192",
          "type": "image/png"
        }
      ],
      "display": "browser",
      "prefer_related_applications": true,
      "related_applications": [
        {
          "platform": "play",
          "id": "com.the.appid"
        }
      ]
    }
```